# ipyparallel Push a tuple to avoid loading it in every engine

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a matrix of MxN size and each space in the matrix has a big list stored with numbers. It looks like this:

```
matrix=[[a,b,c,],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]
```

where a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i are also matrixes that each look like this:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i=[[12,32],[54,54],[54,34],[54,23]]
```

where each pair represent x,y, coordinates.this is for representation only, the real size of the matrixes above are huge.

so my code has to cycle through the main matrix and find max and min values within the submatrixes a,b,c,d..... Because it is not a sequential work, y splitted the job using ipyparallel multicore feature, and it is quite faster. the problem is I have to load the big matrix in each individual core to be able to use and that loading alone takes around 2 seconds. I was looking to the push option but it only works with dictionaries. Is there a way I could transform my matrix to a dictionary or maybe push my matrix?

```
from ipyparallel import client
rc=Client(profile='default')
lv=rc.direct_view()

lv.map_sync(method,(0,1000,2000,3000),(1000,2000,3000,4000))

def method(a,b):
     matrix=np.load('')#here I load the matrix
     #the do all the work here and return desired values.
     return answer
```

Answer (score 0):

found a way, I just sent the matrix as an argument when calling the function.